# convert double number to (IEEE 754) 64-bit binary string representation in c++

Tags: c++, c, string, double, ieee-754

I have a double number, I want to represent it in IEEE 754 64-bit binary string.
Currently i'm using a code like this:

```
double noToConvert;
unsigned long* valueRef = reinterpret_cast<unsigned long*>(&noToConvert);

bitset<64> lessSignificative(*valueRef);
bitset<64> mostSignificative(*(++valueRef));

mostSignificative <<= 32;
mostSignificative |= lessSignificative;

RowVectorXd binArray = RowVectorXd::Zero(mostSignificative.size());
for(unsigned int i = 0; i <mostSignificative.size();i++)
{
    (mostSignificative[i] == 0) ? (binArray(i) = 0) : (binArray(i) = 1);
}
```

The above code just works  fine without any problem. But If you see, i'm using reinterpret_cast and using unsigned long. So, this code is very much compiler dependent. Could anyone show me how to write a code that is platform independent and without using any libraries. i'm ok, if we use the standard libraries and even bitset, but i dont want to use any machine or compiler dependent code.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just by assuming IEEE 754 is already machine dependent.

Comment: Ok, is there any way to do this..?

Comment: C99 provide long double which is 80-bit extended precision for x86_64  computers. But it is the same as double for x86 computers.

Comment: @Geoffroy: maybe for *some* `x86` computers.  Certainly not for all.  That's entirely dependent on the compiler and libraries.  You could also make an `x86_64` system on which `long double` corresponded to the 64-bit type.

Comment: @Geoffroy so, the above code is just fine.? i'm using an 64-bit machine. will it work on 32-bit machine..?

Comment: At least that's what the standard says

Comment: @Geoffroy: what's what which standard says?

Comment: @Jero To have a 64 bits variable use long long, if your compiler include some of C99 in C++. If you use C++11, then it must already be the case.

Answer (score 5):

If you're willing to assume that `double` is the IEEE-754 double type:

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <cstring>

uint64_t getRepresentation(const double number) {
    uint64_t representation;
    memcpy(&representation, &number, sizeof representation);
}
```

If you don't even want to make that assumption:

```
#include <cstring>

char *getRepresentation(const double number) {
    char *representation = new char[sizeof number];
    memcpy(representation, &number, sizeof number);
    return representation;
}
```

Comment: i want to store the result in a binary string. like string s = "0011111111101111111101111100111011011001000101101000011100101011" , but what u suggested me is returning something like ffffff@¬%¿Woò

Comment: @Jero: What I suggested gives you the actual representation in memory.  You can read the bit pattern out from that without invoking undefined behavior.

Answer (score 2):

Why not use the union?

```
bitset<64> binarize(unsigned long* input){
    union binarizeUnion   
    {
        unsigned long* intVal;
        bitset<64> bits;
    } binTransfer;
    binTransfer.intVal=input;
    return (binTransfer.bits);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way to get this is to `memcpy` the double into an array of `char`:

```
char double_as_char[sizeof(double)];
memcpy(double_as_char, &noToConvert, sizeof(double_as_char));
```

and then extract the bits from `double_as_char`. C and C++ define that in the standard as legal.

Now, if you want to actually extract the various components of a `double`, you can use the following:

```
sign= noToConvert<=-0.0f;
int exponent;
double normalized_mantissa= frexp(noToConvert, &exponent);
unsigned long long mantissa= normalized_mantissa * (1ull << 53);
```

Since the value returned by `frexp` is in `[0.5, 1)`, you need to shift it one extra bit to get all the bits in the mantissa as an integer. Then you just need to map that into the binary represenation you want, although you'll have to adjust the exponent to include the implicit bias as well.

Answer (score 1):

The function print_raw_double_binary() in my article [Displaying the Raw Fields of a Floating-Point Number](http://www.exploringbinary.com/displaying-the-raw-fields-of-a-floating-point-number/) should be close to what you want. You'd probably want to replace the casting of double to int with a union, since the former violates "strict aliasing" (although even use of a union to access something different than what is stored is technically illegal).